# Music voice inaudible in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

So I have this strange sound problem in my Ubuntu. I can hear music and ambient sounds when playing songs from YouTube or Spotify, but eventually I don't hear any voices.

When I restart the computer, at first it works fine. But after some time the voice becomes quieter and eventually I don't hear it at all.

This is really annoying. Anyone knows how to resolve this?

`sudo lspci -v` returns among other devices:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at fe8fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

The "sink list":

```
Welcome to PulseAudio 8.0! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2 k 44100 Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 100,14 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfe9fc000 irq 30"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "aab0"
        device.product.name = "Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]"
        device.string = "hdmi:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "ATI R6xx HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100300"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
  * index: 5
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 100,00 ms
    max request: 17 KiB
    max rewind: 17 KiB
    monitor source: 6
    sample spec: s16le 2 k 44100 Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 5
    linked by: 5
    fixed latency: 99,95 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "Generic Analog"
        alsa.id = "Generic Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xfe8fc000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "27d8"
        device.product.name = "NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analogowe stereo"
        device.description = "Wbudowany dźwięk Analogowe stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "VIA Generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:11060397,10438415,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Wyjście liniowe (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Słuchawki (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-lineout>
```

Comment: I don't know what sound package is used and there may be other factors.

Comment: I'll be happy to provide as much details as I can, just give me commands to run.

Comment: try check your drivers with `lspci -v`

Comment: did you check your audio settings with `pacmd` and type `list-sinks` sir? what the state said sir?

Comment: The next time voices fade out, try `pulseaudio -k` instead of reboot. Does this fix the issue again temporarily?

Comment: @MichaelZukowski please check my update answered.

Comment: As [Niclas noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068152/250300), the voice is often placed in the “center” of music. In a stereo recording, it means it is the same in both channels, unlike the rest of the music. Sometimes it useful to [get rid of the voice](https://audio-production.wonderhowto.com/how-to/remove-vocals-from-any-song-make-karaoke-instrumental-track-0163436/) and it can be achieved by subtracting one of the stereo track from the other. Something must have configured to do this in your machine…

Comment: Cable loose or screw loose ... ?

Comment: Headset broken ;(

Comment: @MichaelZukowski Does it mean it turns out to be a hardware problem?

Comment: Unfortunately. yes.

Answer (score 2):

### Hardware problem

It turns out this was a hardware problem caused by a broken headset. However, for other users there are software solutions to look into.

### Software problem

There are programs for karaoke sound manipulation where voices are taken out of the music. Check if you have any of these programs installed and running without being requested:

- [Karaoke Mode for YouTube™ - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/karaoke-mode-for-youtube/ghnaglacgepiijbbkpfdoncgfadgkdck?hl=en-GB)
- [Ubuntu Manpage: performous - The free music and rhythm game](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/performous.6.html)
- [Ubuntu Manpage: pykaraoke - free CDG/MIDI/MPEG karaoke player](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/pycdg.6.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 5.1 system? Voices are often coded through the 'center' channel. I would'n rule out a hardware problem with that speaker. (Been there myself.)

Comment: I have a simple jack output to which I have a simple headset plugged in. It used to work pretty well. The issue started to happen recently.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, your ALSA hasn't been detected by Intel ICH7 Soundcard.

try adding `blacklist i82975x_edac` to `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf` and make `modprobe -r i82975x_edac` and then restart again with `alsa force-reload`.

or perhaps, on your audio settings said :

```
state: SUSPENDED  
suspend cause: IDLE
```

i think you haven't been disabling your suspend-on-idle module.
try adding `#` on `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file.
from `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` to `#load-module module-suspend-on-idle`.

and then kill pulse daemon with `pulseaudio -k` and restart `sudo init 6`.

Hope this helps.